# Distributed Always-On without Domain

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, windows-server, enterprise-edition

We have a requirement to configure a distributed availability group from Data center1 to Data Center2 using SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Edition.

DC1 (two nodes WSFC setup): SQLDB1, SQLDB2

DC2 (two nodes WSFC setup): SQLDB3, SQLDB4

The servers are in workgroups, not in a domain. Is it possible to configure distributed availability groups from DC1 to DC2 without domain?

As per my understanding, using certificates it's possible to configure Distributed SQL always-on if all four nodes are in same cluster. Is my understanding is correct?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation at [Distributed availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017#sql-server-version-and-edition-requirements-for-distributed-availability-groups) states:

> The individual WSFC clusters and their corresponding availability groups follow traditional rules. That is, they can be joined to a domain or not joined to a domain (Windows Server 2016 or later).

Regarding your question about all four nodes being in the same cluster--if they are in the same cluster, then there would be no need to have a distributed availability group (DAG), you would just use an availability group with four replicas.  Additionally, the documentation referenced above states:

> A distributed availability group spans multiple availability groups, each on its own underlying WSFC cluster.

So if it is possible to set up a DAG with all nodes in one cluster, it is contrary to the documentation and may not be supported.

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanks for your reply and comments. The all 4 nodes are NOT in same cluster. SQLDB1 and DB2 are in one cluster (WSFC_CLUST1) & SQLDB3 and DB4 are in one cluster (WSFC_CLUST2). In this scenario, is it possible to configure distributed availability group (DAG) from DC1 to DC2? If, YES, can you please share high level steps to achieve this? I have done DAG setup where servers are in domain, but here the servers are not in domain. I am not sure what steps I have to follow here.

Comment: The documentation has the high level steps.  I've never done it so I don't have any further information.

Comment: Your question says, " if all four nodes are in same cluster. ". Did you mean to say "not in the same cluster"?

Comment: Always on is not easy to support. Distributed AG added on top of that complexity. Have you look at other option for your DR ? (ex : Use Log shipping in your DC2)

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher This.  Distributed AGs over domain-less clusters is a high-complexity solution.  Super-useful in the right scenario.  By "coincidence", the feature that appeared shortly after Azure SQL Database Active-Geo Replication did.  But it's not the simplest solution by a long shot.  Regular AGs are straightforward.  Little worse than log shipping, and much more useful.  But Distributed AGs and Domain-less clusters are more complex to implement and operate.

Comment: The key to this is @TonyHinkle's "I've never done it so I don't have any further information".  It's not something you should attempt without a Microsoft Premier Field Engineer, or a Partner who has implemented it before, because you won't find many people who have implemented and operated it here.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft.  I suspected as much as to how widely deployed something like this is--nice to see confirmation.

Comment: Thanks to all for your comments and suggestions. I found high level steps in below blog. Can you please review and suggest if i can proceed with steps mentioned in below blog:  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/04/18/sql-server-steps-to-deploy-distributed-availability-group-windows-clusters-in-different-domains/

Comment: Is it possible to test above steps in MS temp VM's? i mean is there any link of MS to create temp VM's ...i can create 4 VM's without domain , configure cluster and install sql and test above steps?